# Buscar todos los archivos que contienen una cadena de texto en Linux

Tags: linux, grep

> Pregunta original : [Finding all files containing a text string on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux) de [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954986/nathan)

Estoy intentando encontrar una forma de escanear todo mi sistema Linux en busca de archivos con una específica cadena de texto. Sólo para dejar claro, busco una cadena de texto en el archivo, no el nombre del archivo.

Cuando estaba buscando como hacerlo, encontré esta solución en dos ocasiones:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'cadena-de-texto-para-buscar' {} \;
```

Sin embargo, no funcionó. Al parecer,  muestra todos los archivos en el sistema.

¿Es esta la mejor forma de hacerlo? ¿Cuál debería serlo sino? Esta habilidad de buscar cadenas de textos dentro de archivos me sería extraordinariamente útil para algunos proyectos de programación que estoy haciendo.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/1983854

Answer (score 11):

`grep -Ril "texto" *` es mi forma favorita de realizar esta búsqueda.

Sin embargo, también es útil utilizar `find` para obtener el listado de ficheros con los filtros necesarios y luego ejecutar `grep` para ver cuáles contienen la cadena que buscamos:

```
find -type f -exec grep -l "texto" {} +
```

Esto busca archivos solamente y en todos ellos busca el texto "texto". Si hay alguna coincidencia, sale automáticamente gracias al uso de `-l` (L minúscula), por lo que la salida de este comando es el listado de archivos que contienen tal cadena.

Answer (score 9):

Usa esto:

```
grep -Ril "texto-a-encontrar-aqui" /
```

**R** es para que sea recursivo, **i** es para ignorar el case  y **l** para mostrar los nombres de los archivos.

Comment: Supongo que estás usando [mi respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16956844/1983854) en SOen como referencia. En tal caso, sería útil mencionar por qué usar `-i` (o, en general, por qué no). Igualmente, hay que tener en cuenta que puede ser mejor usar `-r` que `-R` para no seguir los links.

Comment: el uso de i para el case, si se conoce la manera en la que esta escrito el texto puede hacer el comando muy ineficiente si se busca en muchos ficheros, pero no esta mal el que se comente que existe esa opcion por si no se recuerda como esta escrito el texto que se desea buscar , pero tener en cuenta que es un parametro que puede marcar una gran diferencia en tiempo segun que casos Saludos

Comment: la pregunta dice... busca de archivos con una específica cadena de texto... a mi entender el usuario conoce la cadena exacta que esta buscado, de ser conocida el uso se i no es muy eficiente a mi entender Saludos

Answer (score 4):

> Respuesta original de [Finding all files containing a text string on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux/16957078#16957078) de [rakib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231815/rakib)

Haz lo siguiente:

```
grep -rnw '/ruta/donde/quieres/buscar'  -e "patrón"
```

`-r` o `-R` es recursivo, `-n` es número de la línea y `-w` significa que coincide con la palabra. `-l` (letra L) puede ser añadida para obtener el nombre del archivo.

Junto con esto, los parámetros --exclude o --include  podría ser usado para una búsqueda eficiente.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
grep --include=\*.{c,h} -rw '/ruta/donde/quieres/buscar' -e "patrón"
```

Esto solamente buscará entre los archivos que tienen la extensión .c o .h. Del mismo modo un ejemplo del uso de --exclude:

```
grep --exclude=*.o -rw '/ruta/donde/quieres/buscar' -e "patrón"
```

Lo anterior excluirá de la búsqueda los archivos que terminan con extensión .o. De la misma forma se pueden excluir/incluir directorios através del parámetro --exclude-dir y --include-dir, lo siguiente muestra como integrar --exclude-dir:

```
grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2, *.dst} -rw '/ruta/donde/quieres/buscar' -e "patrón"
```

Esto funcionó muy bien para mi, para conseguir casi lo mismo que propones tu.

Para más opciones:

```
man grep
```

Comment: Buena traducción de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

Answer (score 3):

Usted puede tratar de usar lo siguiente:

> ```
> grep    options         pattern          input_file_names 
>
> grep    -Rl     "cadenaDeTextoABuscar"         ./
> ```

Shell:

```
grep -Rl  "cadenaDeTextoABuscar" ./

./directorioDondeEstaElFichero/NombreDelFicheroQueContieneLaCadena.cpp
```

el uso de `R` es para indicar que la busqueda sera de forma recursiva y `l` para que muestre el nombre del fichero que contiene la cadena indicada

Puede mirar el manual para otras opciones (link en ingles).

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Command_002dline-Options

Answer (score 3):

Creo que esto te tendría que funcionar:

**Find** tiene una sintaxis muy simple solo hace falta escribir

```
find [ruta] [expresión_de_búsqueda] [acción]
```

- **[ruta]** cualquier ruta desde donde inicia la búsqueda, por ejemplo, `/home/usuario`.
- **[expresión_de_búsqueda]** por defecto `-print` muestra el resultado de la búsqueda.
- **[acción]** comando Linux a ejecutarse sobre cada directorio o archivo encontrado

**Ejemplos:**

> Todos los archivos pertenecientes a Guillermo

```
find /home -user guillermo
```

> Busca archivos con el la palabra informe en el nombre.

```
find /home -name informe
```

> Realiza la misma búsqueda ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

```
find /home -iname informe
```

> archivos que empiezan con numero entre 0 y 9

```
find /home -name "[0-9]*"
```

> archivos que empiezan con “A” o “g”.

```
find /home -name "[Ag]*"
```

> archivos que empiezan entre “w” a “z” y con extensión “.py”

```
find /home -name "[w-z]*.py"
```

Es posible buscar por fechas, tamaño, las combinaciones son muchas y las encontrarás en la ayuda de `find`.

Comment: Nótese que esto buscaría archivos cuyo *nombre* contiene tal cadena de texto. La pregunta se refiere al *contenido*.

Comment: Insisto, porque parece seguir recibiendo votos: **esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta que se está formulando**. Para nada. Se pregunta por buscar _dentro_ del fichero, no en su nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que en la ruta relativa donde nos encontramos, se encuentra en el mismo directorio (o en subdirectorios/directorios hijos) un archivo con la cadena de texto "seis" en su interior:

```
find . -name "*" | xargs grep -i "seis"
```

Comment: Muy poco práctico: buscar todos los ficheros con `find`, cargar el buffer y finalmente ir haciendo `grep` en todos. Además, ¿qué hay de los nombres de fichero algo raros? Con `xargs` puede dar problemas. Véase [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/1983854)

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo esta sentencia:

```
grep -rl "string" /path
```

donde:

- -r (o --recursive) es utilizada para verificar al subdirectorios de /path, mientras que
- -l (or --files-with-matches) es utilizada solo para imprimir los nombres de archivos de aquellos que cumplen la condición, en lugar de las lineas en donde se hizo el match (incluso mejora la velocidad, dado que grep frena la lectura del archivo en el primer match, evitando recorrer el archivo completo).

Ejemplo:

```
grep -rl "hola mundo" /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Esto solución ya se expuso hace años.

Comment: @fedorqui cuando respondí esta pregunta no revisé a detalle las demás y es cierto, tiene simulitudes (muchas) con respuestas previamente dadas. Sin embargo se diferencia en el desarrollo de la misma. Si revisamos [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/23233) en meta, no hay razón para que la respuesta desaparezca o sea votada negativamente ya que no es un plagio ni mucho menos. Es un tema complejo que no se ha tratado pero puede ser la oportunidad de aclararlo

Comment: 1º de todo, yo no he votado negativamente: la respuesta es correcta. 2º, la pregunta que mencionas en meta no es canónica ni escrita por [se], sino algo colaborativo que crece con el tiempo. Por tanto, que no se mencione tu caso allí no quiere decir que sea correcto. Finalmente, se ha discutido muy extensamente (por ejemplo [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96412/209901)) sobre publicar la misma respuesta pasado un tiempo. [En SO las borran](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326206/1983854) porque, ¿qué estás aportando que no se hubiera dicho ya? Mejor editar la respuesta que ya existía.

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta ya se expuso hace tiempo, aporta cosas nuevas (una descripción más detallada y alternativas para los parámetros). Quizás podría mantenerse o plantearse como una edición como dice fedorqui.