# Cómo buscar un archivo con find

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

Buenas, estoy tratando te buscar un archivo con el nombre **"hibernate.cfg.xml"** con el comando `find` y  no lo encuentra, pero yo se que existe y en varios proyectos bajo mi home
El comando que estoy ejecutando es:

```
$ find /home/santi hibernate.cfg.xml
```

¿Cómo sería la correcta forma de buscarlo ?

Comment: trate con -iname o -name  `find /home/santi -iname hibernate.cfg.xml` Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel gracias angel, funciono con iname perfectamente, quieres responder así queda respondida la pregunta . Saludos

Comment: me alegro que te funcionara ahora cuando tenga un poco de tiempo la agrego como respuesta lo de iname es para que ignore use el case sensitive, por si el nombre del fichero esta en mayusculas ect, name para el nombre tal cual se escribe. Saludos new por  comentario de debajo: en ese caso usa -name

Comment: Gracias @AngelAngel Lo curioso es que el archivo que buscaba estaba correctamente ingresado el nombre. por eso es que no utilice la opción de ignorar como estaba escrito el nombre. . Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usted puede tratar de usar por ejemplo:

`find /home/santi -iname hibernate.cfg.xml`

---

- `-iname` iname ignorara el case sensitive, puede usarlo en el caso de que sepa el nombre del fichero pero no recuerde si estaba con mayusculas o minisculas: por ejemplo si el fichero fuera`hiBerNate.cfg.xml`, o  `hibernate.cfg.xml` usando esta opcion lo encontrara sin tener en cuenta el uso de las mayusculas o minusculas. `find /home/santi -iname hibernate.cfg.xml`

o

- `-name` name solo encontrara el fichero, si es exactamente igual al que se le indica por ejemplo: si el fichero fuera`hiBerNate.cfg.xml`, usando esta opcion NO encontrara dicho fichero pues tiene en cuenta las mayusculas o minusculas. `find /home/santi -name hibernate.cfg.xml`

---

para mas opciones puede mirar estos link:

1. http://www.linuxtotal.com.mx/index.php?cont=info_admon_022
2. http://www.comoinstalarlinux.com/comandos-linux-find-con-ejemplos/
3. http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

---

esta pregunta cuenta con varias repuesta, que igual, si no es lo mismo que usted pregunta, puede que le sea util en algun momento:

[Buscar todos los archivos que contienen una cadena de texto en Linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479/buscar-todos-los-archivos-que-contienen-una-cadena-de-texto-en-linux/1485#1485)

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar en todos los subdirectorios se usa `/`

```
$ find / -iname "hibernate.cfg.xml"
```

Para buscar en un folder especifico, por ejemplo `home/santi` :

```
$ find /home/santi -iname "hibernate.cfg.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quisieras buscar desde el directorio actual hacia adentro, y supongamos que quisieras ampliar la búsqueda a todos los archivos que empiezan con "hibernate" puedes hacer:

```
find . name "hibernate*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /ruta/donde/buscar/ -type f -name hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Argumentos de la función **find**:

- **-type** declara el tipo a buscar:

  - **f** (files) para archivos.
  - **d** (directory) directorios (folder o carpeta).
- **-name** especifica el nombre o patrón del documento que quieres encontrar. Este comando permite el uso de comodines (leer [wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)) para mayor información), pero para ello se requiere usar dentro de comillas simples (') o dobles (") ejemplo:

  - find ./ -name *algo.xml **// Daría un error**
  - find ./ -name '*algo.xml' **// Daría el resultado esperado**

Si no se especifica el tipo de archivo a buscar, también podría imprimir en la lista de resultados una carpeta con el nombre ***hibernate.cfg.xml***.